# Rails routes and ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have problem:

My routes:

```
match 'questions/get_label/:id' => 'questions#get_label'
                               ,:as => :question_get_label, :via =>  :post
```

My JS:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'questions/get_label/'+id,
        type: "POST",


        success: function(){
            //$('.preloader').hide()

        }
    });
```

Server Answer:

```
No route matches [PATCH] "/questions/get_label/2"
```

What I miss?

Comment: What's the rest of the Ajax call?

Comment: Is the `match` route nested within any block? Also, you might have forgotten to add a `type: "POST"` to your ajax call.

Comment: ok i try to send non existing data and it shows route error..

Comment: Try replacing the route with: `post 'questions/get_label/:id' => 'questions#get_label', :as => :question_get_label`

Comment: Also, It's not a good idea to make a `POST` request to *get* some data. You're request should be a `GET` one.